How to display text over image without background-color showing
tl;dr - How to avoid background-color showing on text in front of images in css.
Background
The w3Schools site for displaying text over an image (link here) uses a relative-container, absolute-child setup. Under normal circumstances this works fine (see code and image below).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html> 


However, if your file has a background-color set, that background color will bleed through on the absolute positioned elements (see code image below).
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
   background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html> 


Question
How can one have text overlay an image without this "background color bleed through" issue coming up? The goal is to have the absolute positioned elements have no background color, or a transparent one (setting the absolute element's background-color to transparent doesn't seem to work).
I'm aware that absolute positioning elements are treated differently than in-line elements, but I'm unclear on how to resolve this issue. The accepted solution for this post seems to work if trying to set the absolute element to have a specific color, but my goal is to have no background color so that only the text is shown in front of the image.

Downvoters rarely explain themselves, so don't expect they will do so. I followed your question, and I think you got 2 downvotes in the beginning, probably because your question didn't have any code, apart from code in the images. People don't like that. People might downvote your question because they think w3Schools is a bad resource to learn coding from. Who knows? Three downvotes isn't all that bad, it just means that the question doesn't contribute much to Stack Overflow. Best ignore it. There are many things on Stack Overflow that are irritating and best ignored.

You are setting the background color of everything (including divs) to black. If you want to change the background color of the body, replace * with body:


body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>




You can create a new CSS method (like noBackground in my code snippet, applied in top and center overlaid texts) and apply it to each overlaid class.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
*{
  background-color: black;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.noBackground {
  background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left noBackground">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right noBackground">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered noBackground">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html> 




Not correcting the * select all elements is a mistake in my eyes. There can be no good reason to set the background of all elements to black in the first place.

I know @KIKOSoftware, but not everything is always black or white. For example, many frameworks default to the css through skins, not allowing you to remove that css. Having no more information about the user's example, I have only proposed a solution as close to its initial code as possible. Of course, if I had designed the css from scratch, I would never have used *

Yes, staying close to the original code can be a good idea. However, the original seems just a copy of the w3Schools example with the * select added. Maybe Jwok thinks this is the proper way to set the background color of the web page?
